# List assignment index out of range

Tags: python, arrays, list

My code is giving me the error of:

```
    list_subs[n][4] = np.random.normal(list_subs[n][1], list_subs[n][2])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range.
```

I have searched for this error and i still can't find what is the problem.

Edit: Full Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 420, in run_nodebug
File "C:\Documents and Settings\jhsilva\Desktop\Monte carlo\Teste.py", line 71, in 
generateRandomNumbers(list_subs)
File "C:\Documents and Settings\jhsilva\Desktop\Monte carlo\Teste.py", line 41, in generateRandomNumbers
list_subs[n][4] = np.random.normal(list_subs[n][1], list_subs[n][2])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

The Code

```
def generateRandomNumbers(list_subs):

    for n in range(len(list_subs)):

        string = list_subs[n][3]
        string = string.lower()

        if(string == "normal"):
            list_subs[n][4] = np.random.normal(list_subs[n][1], list_subs[n][2])
            print("Numero gerado:",list_subs[n][4])


variables = [v for v in variables if v not in special]


list_subs=[[0 for col in range(6)] for row in range(len(variables)-1)]

#This prints fine
print(len(list_subs))

#this prints fine too
print(list_subs[0][4])

for n in range(len(variables)):
    if n>0:
        (media,desviopadrao,distribuicao) = eval(input("For variable "+variables[n]+" input: median, std, distr \n"))
        list_subs[n-1] = [variables[n], media, desviopadrao, distribuicao]

N = eval(input("Qual o numero de iteracoes que deseja:"))

Var = []
for n in range(N):
    generateRandomNumbers(list_subs)
    Var.append(calcEq(formula))
```

Comment: **Where** is it giving you that exception? What is the *full* traceback?

Comment: Don't use `string` as a variable name, and don't use InitialCaps for variables either; and what happens if `list_sub[n]` doesn't have 3 elements?

Comment: I initialized list_subs[] as a 6xvariable matrix. I added 4 fields and then  in generateRandomNumbers i was trying to fill the 5th field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_subs[n-1] = [variables[n], media, desviopadrao, distribuicao]
```

You are setting `list_subs` to be a list of lists of length `4`. This means that the valid indeces are `0, 1, 2, 3`. In `generateRandomNumbers` you access index `4`, which is invalid.

---

Security note: Don't use `eval(input(...))`. If you want to parse numbers/tuples etc simply use `ast.literal_eval`, which is a safe alternative.

Comment: Yes but i initialized the list_subs with 6 columns:
list_subs=[[0 for col in range(6)] for row in range(len(variables)-1)]
 Since i didn't fill the whole columns it reshape itself?
 Didn't knew about "ast.literal_eval"

Comment: @humberto The line that I have highlighted **replaces** the content at index `n-1` with thenew list. If you want to set only the first 4 elements of the previous content then use `list_subs[n-1][:4] = [variables[n], media, desviopadrao, distribucao]`.

Comment: Oh. i didn´t knew. I thought since i initialized as a 6 column it would always be 6 column. Thanks that did the trick :)

Comment: @humberto Remember that a list does *not* know what objects it contains, so how could he understand that you wanted to modify the first 4 items of the sublist?. It *never* operates on them. A list allows you to group object together in a sequence. Doing `list[index]` retrieves the object at the given index, and `list[index] = value` assigns `value` to the given index. If you want to operate with the objects contained you first have to retrieve them(e.g. `list_subs[n-1][:4] = [...]` first obtains the element at index `n-1` after that it assigns `[...]` to the first four elements(the `[:4]`).